# Replacing a string with NaN or 0

Tags: python, pandas, replace, nan, dtype

I have a data file that I'm cleaning, and the source uses '--' to indicate missing data.
I ultimately need to have this data field be either an integer or float.  But I am not sure how to remove the string.

I specified the types in a type_dict statement before importing the csv file.
6 of my 8 variables correctly came in as an integer or float.  Of course, the two that are still objects are the ones I need to fix.

I've tried using the df = df.var.str.replace('--', '')
I've tried using the df.var.fillna(df.var.mode().values[0], inplace=True)
(and I wonder if I need to just change the values '0' to '--')

My presumption is that if I can empty those cells in some fashion, I can define the variable as an int/float.

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple, have walked away and come back, but am just not figuring it out.

Comment: If a pandas column is of type string, then it will always be of type string.  If you use an `apply` function, you can either convert the value to integer, or return 0 if it's not one you want.  Note that there are no `nan`s for integers.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this cleaning input before antering into pandas

```
import sys
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = StringIO(file.read().replace('--', '0'))

df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, we figured out two options to make this work:

solution 1:
df = df.replace(r'^--$', np.nan, regex=True)

solution 2 (a simplified version of #1):
df = df.replace(r'--', np.nan)

Both gave the expected output of empty cells when I exported the csv into a spreadsheet.  And then when I reimported that intermediate file, I had floats instead of strings as expected.